# La Classico Stainless Steel Stock Pot and Multi purpose steamer

Tags: steaming, stainless-steel

Has anyone seen steamer without holes on the bottom but the holes are   the side instead of the steam trays? The side of the trays is double layer to accommodate for the steam holes. I’m looking for instructions. Thanks.

Comment: You have this thing? [Edit] in a picture. You want instructions for how to use it? Boil water under it, typically, for steaming.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this type?

[image]

If you use the tall insert & fill with water it boils, whilst allowing you you to lift it out to drain. Use the short insert with an inch of water [or not enough to reach it, if you're stacking], it steams.

Google doesn't find anything at all for 'La Classico'.

Comment: The inserts you pictured have holes on the bottom. The ones on the short tray are visible, the ones in the asparagus insert aren't, but I don't remember seeing a similar one without holes in the bottom.

Comment: @rumtscho - yes, but the same would apply if the holes were on the sides only - of which I could not find a picture. Fill it right up, it boils, just an inch, it steams. OP could post a picture if it really is nothing like this. I can't imagine many pans that need instructions, tbh ;)

Comment: The way I understand the question, the OP is looking for instructions specifically because they are puzzled by their steamer being unlike a standard steamer with holes on the bottom. So it is more of a "how do I use this differently from a standard steamer" than "how do I use a steamer in general".

Comment: I have no experience with this particular type, but I would assume that such a steamer would be like when you place a plate of items into the steamer, as the steam can’t come at the food from all sides.  I might still use a plate so if things stuck, it stuck to the plate rather than the steamer basket